# Force HTTPS with AWS Elastic load balancer

Tags: apache-2.2, amazon-web-services, http, https, amazon-elb

I need to redirect all incoming HTTP traffic to HTTPS on my elastic load balancer.

I tired using Apache mod_rewrite:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
 RewriteRule !/status https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

Taking advantage of the X-Forwarded-Proto header added by the load balancer, this rule should instruct the users browser to request the HTTPS version of the same URL.

So far It doesn't work (no redirection happens).

What am I doing wrong?

Is there a better way to do this?

EDIT:

This eventually worked:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !=https
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I assume you have the ELB set to accept traffic on both HTTP/80 and HTTPS/443, but port-forward all to HTTP.

If you want to use your method (which is clever), are you sure what you get isn't `%{X-Forwarded-Proto}` -- the `HTTP:` prefix looks odd to me.  Other than that, this looks right to me.

If this is in a virtual host or the main server config and it's still not working, you can add

```
RewriteLog rewrite-log
RewriteLogLevel 3
```

then look in the file `rewrite-log` to see what's actually going on.  This file can be incredibly verbose, start with lower levels.  Logging cannot be initiated from `.htaccess` files.

(I would suggest you make the flags on the `RewriteRule` `[R=301,L]` which will cause the server to send back a 301 response, which tells search engines to consider the redirect permanent, and update its links accordingly.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, It looks like the [R=301,L] was part of the solution.

Comment: Glad you found something that worked, but the flags `[L,R]` should be fine other than the naked `R` returns an http 302 status.  The order of flags shouldn't matter.  More likely it's something about the change in the `RewriteRule` which is different in 2 ways 1) it will not rewrite http requests to `/status` any more, and 2) it uses a capture group and back-reference (`(.*)` then `$1`) instead of the `%{REQUEST_URI}` variable.  It might be helpful to others to see if the flags really were the cause, or perhaps it was something else.

Comment: I think I have narrowed it down to the use of != instead of !

Comment: HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto and X-Forwarded-Proto both worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to add my experience as I struggled for hours before realizing that my heartbeat file had an unescaped dot in it (/alive.html). Duh.

The second problem was that the main domain was not redirecting, but files were. So http://domain.com/hello.html was redirecting to https://domain.com/hello.html, but http://domain.com was not.

Here's what I put in my .htaccess file that worked for me:

```
RewriteEngine On
# SSL connection forced
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/alive\.html$
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem turned out to be that the !https condition was breaking the health check.

changing the condition to ^http$  made it work

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} ^http$
```

found that here:
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=641930